# Nedit stopped working on my iMac running High Sierra 10.13.4

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editor

I installed Nedit on my iMac this weekend. I used it several times and it worked fine. For some reason last night it quit working. When I type Nedit in the terminal window I just get the message

`NEdit: Can't open display`.

Using Homebrew again, I reinstalled Nedit using

```
brew reinstall nedit
```

Nedit still refuses to work. I am totally confused since it worked fine for a day and a half. Any clue why it stopped working?  Was the fact that it worked the most confusing issue or the fact that it stopped.  Its version 5.7 of Nedit and claims that its for High Sierra.

Comment: What is the value of $DISPLAY? Seems like you don’t have XQuartz running or your env var was lost

Comment: I started XQuartz before trying Nedit.  When I type 'echo $DISPLAY', I get a blank return.

Comment: Ah, that is the issue then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks from your comment that your display variable is not set. Ensure you have an X-Server running (I. E. XQuartz) and then set your display environment variable first with:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Launching applications from within the XQuartz terminal will have the `$DISPLAY` env var set automatically. You can make this change persist by adding that line to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
echo 'export DISPLAY=:0' >> ~/.profile
```

Note that in my setup, XQuartz automatically sets `$DISPLAY` for me without my needing to do this, so you may want to re-install XQuartz.(Or ask a follow-up question about why that behavior isn't working)

Comment: Sure. Note that you'll need to do this for every terminal session. You may want to add that to a `.profile` file, or launch from within the terminal in XQuartz

Comment: Josh, I added "export DISPLAY=:0 to my .bash_profile. This seems to work.  Thanks again.